# Best way to design the below mentioned data structure

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, data-structures, dictionary

I have this class.

```
class event_t {

public:
  event_t(String *_session_time, String *_event_type, String *_table_name, String *_num_of_events);
  ~event_t();
   char *table_name;
   char *event_type;  
   pthread_mutex_t lock;
   pthread_cond_t cond;
   int num_of_events_threshold;
   double time_out; 
   int num_of_events_so_far; 
};
```

Then I have a stl::map.

```
std::map <char*, std::list<event_t*>, cmp_str > all_events;
```

I want to keep a single entry for same table_name and event_type. Whenever a new request occurs I want to delete the old event if it has same table_name and event_type and is present in std::list. But when I delete this old event object, the map's key which happens to be same char* table_name also gets deleted.

My mapping is something like:

```
map[event_t->table_name] = stl::list<event_t>
```

Comment: So don't use a `char*` as the key (or for that matter, the data members `event_type` and `table_name` either). Use `std::string`

Comment: I have to use char* because the all the parts are written using custom String class which can be converted to c-style string. I think converting that to std::string and using would be a overkill.

Comment: Ah.. ok. On that, pardon the obvious, but in having `std::string` in your toolbox, a custom `String` arguably extends to the same overkill, but you gotta dance with the one you brought, I suppose. =P

Comment: well some parts are using std::string but the entire code base still doesn't use it. I get arguments to constructor of event_t class as custom String object. (This is a fork of mysql).

Comment: I don't suppose you could just use `String` indexes into your map and have `String` member vars? Or as a utter resort-to-chaos, use `std::shared_ptr<char>` as the key and member (but egads thats horrid). Honestly I would use `std::string` regardless. Anything else is just an abomination.